# EXCEL - Column A has 554 SKU's and column B has 1872. Not in not in order. How do I get them in order with the matching data first?

Tags: excel

I have over 100 vendor lists I need to sort and align for a software system migration. If anyone knows this answer I will be grateful for any advice. I tried =VLOOKUP, =MATCH. I cannot figure out how to organize the data with the matching SKU's first.

This is an example of what the list looks like.

```
#105:CR1910-RT10G0  #105:GR1019-SL54FT
#105:CR1910-RT10M0  #105:GR1035-SL54F0
#105:GL1405-M078F0  #105:GR1035-SL54H0
#105:GL1407-0306C0  #105:GR1035-SL54P0
#105:GL1409-0306C0  #105:GR1019-SL54FT
#105:GL1409-0312C0  #105:GR1730-SL54P0
#105:GL1409-BR16C0  #105:GR1838-SL54H0
#105:GL1409-CL12C0  #105:GR1471-SL54P0
#105:GL1409-STGRCF  #105:MB2172-SL54H0
#105:GL1412-0306C0  #105:MB2172-SL34H0
#105:GL1413-0306C0  #105:MB2172-SL54P0
#105:GL1428-0306C0  #105:MB2172-SL34P0
#105:GL1428-0306F0  #105:MB1810-SL34P0
#105:GL1428-0312C0  #105:MB1779-SL54P0
#105:GL1428-M078F1  #105:GR1768-SL54H0
#105:GL1428-ML12C0  #105:MB1809-SL54H0
#105:GL1428-STGRCF  #105:MB1809-SL34H0
#105:GL1430-BRICF0  #105:MB1809-SL54P0
#105:GL1512-0208C0  #105:MB1809-SL34P0
#105:GL1512-0306C0  #105:GR1234-SL54P0
#105:GL1512-0306F0  #105:GR1879-SL54P0
#105:GL1512-0312C0  #105:GR1879-SL54V0
#105:GL1512-0312F0  #105:MB2053-SL54P0
#105:GL1512-BR16C0  #105:MB1806-SL54H0
```

Comment: Is this what you are asking: Columns A and B are related, I just want to see the ones where they are equal first? Or is it: A SKU in column A may or may not exist in column B, and I want to see if it does?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your first question is the one I am looking for. I used the exact formula and when I tried to copy it down, it was just a repeat of A1 all the way down column B.

Answer (score 1):

Move your second column to another column, I used column C.

Then in new second column use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:A,1,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

Then sort the new second column and the old second column on the new second column.

[image: ![enter image description here]

At this point you can either hide column A or Copy and paste the values in Column B and delete Column A.

---

To do this in VBA:

```
Sub MySort()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim t As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet17") 'Change to your sheet
With ws
    .[B:B].Insert
    For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        t = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, .Range("A:A"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If t > 0 Then rng.Offset(, -1).Value = rng.Value
    Next rng

    .Range("A:A").Delete
    .Range("A:B").Sort Key1:=.Range("A1")
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```